# Working with localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am building an online os and have an issue.
Is it possible to add data to the current values ​​of the local storage object without removing the current values​​?

Comment: what type of data do you want to add? arrays, lists, objects, strings, numbers?

Comment: Just set the value equal to the current value plus whatever you want to append to it? No need to remove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kind of.  All local storage variables (as far as I know. correct me if I'm wrong) are stored as strings.  So "adding" a bit of data to a local storage variable could be done by appending it to the existing value. e.g.

```
localStorage["myHandle"] += "blah";
```